# plotly table conditional formatting- colored text

Tags: pandas, plotly-python

how to apply colors to values of a dataframe like below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
'col2': ['', '+1%', '+4%', '-6%', '', '+0%', '+5%'],
'col3': ['' , '-2%', '+0%', '+9%', '', '-1%', '+6%'],
'col4': ['', '-7.5%', '+3.75%', '+5.2%', '', '-2.34%', '-3.17%']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

font_color=['black']+[['red' if v else 'green' for v in df[k].str.contains('-')] for k in df.columns]


table_trace = go.Table(
                 header = dict(height = 50,
                               values = [['<b>Col1</b>'], ['<b>Col2</b>'], ['<b>Col3</b>'], ['<b>Col4</b>']],
                               align = ['left']*3,
                               fill_color = '#386dea',
                               font_color = '#fcfcfc',
                               font_size =14),
                 cells = dict(values = [df['col1'], df['col2'], list(df['col3']), list(df['col4'])],
                              line = dict(color='#506784'),
                              align = ['left']*3,
                              font_color=font_color,
                              font_family="Arial", 
                              font_size=14,   
                              height = 30,
                              fill = dict(color='rgb(245,245,245)'))
                             )
                 

layout = go.Layout(width=400, height=415, autosize=False, 
              title_text='Table title',
                   title_x=0.5, showlegend=False)
fig = go.Figure(data=[table_trace], layout=layout)
```

I want to color values with ‘-’ as green and others as red apart from first column. I tried solution mentioned above, but it is randomly coloring the values, not the way I want. Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

- coded your logic using **pandas** / **numpy** capabilities and it works
- also simplified your columns and values logic

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
'col2': ['', '+1%', '+4%', '-6%', '', '+0%', '+5%'],
'col3': ['' , '-2%', '+0%', '+9%', '', '-1%', '+6%'],
'col4': ['', '-7.5%', '+3.75%', '+5.2%', '', '-2.34%', '-3.17%']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

font_color=df.apply(lambda s: np.where(s.name == "col1", "black",
                                       np.where(s.str.contains("-"), "green", "red"),)).T.values

table_trace = go.Table(
                 header = dict(height = 50,
                               values = [f"<b>{c.title()}</b>" for c in df.columns],
                               align = ['left']*3,
                               fill_color = '#386dea',
                               font_color = '#fcfcfc',
                               font_size =14),
                 cells = dict(values = df.T.values,
                              line = dict(color='#506784'),
                              align = ['left']*3,
                              font_color=font_color,
                              font_family="Arial", 
                              font_size=14,   
                              height = 30,
                              fill = dict(color='rgb(245,245,245)'))
                             )
                 

layout = go.Layout(width=400, height=415, autosize=False, 
              title_text='Table title',
                   title_x=0.5, showlegend=False)
fig = go.Figure(data=[table_trace], layout=layout)
fig
```